# Post Views Code Hacks

Tags: php, functions, views

```
// Post views
    function getPostViews($postID){
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            return "0 View";
        }
        return $count.' Views';
    }
    function setPostViews($postID) {
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }
    }
```

The code above remembers and displays post views but there is two problems with it:

1. When there is 1 view it should produce the word "view" not "views"  With all other numbers it should say "views" (as it currently does.)
2. No commas are added tot he number displayed.  Instead of a number displaying as 1,234 it will display as 1234.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Post views
    function getPostViews($postID){
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
            return "0 View";
        } 
        if ($count == '1') {
        return $count.' View';
        } else {
        $count = number_format((int)$count);
        return $count.' Views';
       }
    }
    function setPostViews($postID) {
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Giri Will this work with caching plugins, like WP Super cache? I am not sure that post views will continue to count when page is served from disk as static .html file?